# Microsoft graph live status monitoring

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

Is there any portal where we can check the live status of different Microsoft Graph endpoints? Something like [we have for Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/status/)?

Recently when accessing some Graph endpoints from India we are getting lots of `504` on random endpoints, sometimes we also get `503`.

Couple of months back all our calls were responded by the South India data center, now all calls are responded by the North (and sometimes West) Europe data centers.

Are there some issues with South India data center or the calls are directed because our Azure AD app is hosted in Europe data center?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There isn't a central "Service Status" page for Microsoft Graph.

Keep in mind that Microsoft Graph maps to a number a number of underlying services. For most Microsoft Graph endpoints, you can assess the availability using the service health pages for Azure and Office:

- [Azure Status](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/status/) - for endpoints that rely on Azure Active Directory resources (users, groups, etc.)
- [O365 Service Health](https://portal.office.com/servicestatus) - for endpoints that rely on consumer O365 resources (Outlook.com, personal OneDrive, etc.)
- [O365 Admin Portal Health](https://portal.office.com/adminportal/home#/servicehealth) - for endpoints that rely on organizational O365 resources (SharePoint, OneDrive for Business, Exchange, Intune, etc.)

Comment: It's almost two years later and Microsoft **still** does not have any production monitoring or status information, and no apparent way to log (possible) service issues?  Isn't Graph the Microsoft-recommended way forward to access O365 services?

Comment: A recent (silent) failure of the Graph webhook subscription system underscored the need for some status monitoring. They do have a [ticket](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/1726) for this.

Comment: yes @AWeber Graph is Microsoft recommended way to access O365 services.