# Does Microsoft Teams Graph API has a status page to show of un-usual activity

Tags: microsoft-graph-teams

Recently we have experienced long delay(Sometimes more than 15 minutes) in change notification for chat\channel message subscription. Microsoft Teams Graph API document (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks#latency) latency will be within 10 seconds to 60 seconds.

Does Microsoft \ Microsoft Teams \ Microsoft Teams Graph API  has a status page to show these kind of un-usual activity ?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46594553/microsoft-graph-live-status-monitoring